# Differentiablity of a Gaussian Process with no Correlation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X\equiv\{X_{t}\}_{t\geq0}$ be a process such that $X_{t}\sim N(0,1)$
for all $t\geq0$ and Cov$(X_s,X_t)=0$ for all $s,t$. That is any finite number of given points are i.i.d. samples of an standard normal distribution ($X$ is being used to model a rough surface). Is $X$ a well-defined Gaussian process? Are the sample paths of $X$ Differentiable?

Comment: This is not a homework question. I would appreciate any help .

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter whether it is a homework question or not; adding your own thoughts/ideas helps people on this site to  know what help you need. (By the way, the title of your question is misleading since your question does not contain any information about the correlation of the process.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ a stochastic process such that

- $X_t \sim N(0,1)$ for $t \geq 0$
- $X_{t_1},\ldots,X_{t_n}$ are independent for any $0 \leq t_1 < \ldots < t_n$

A process with these properties is a special case of a so-called *white noise process*. By the independence of the random vector $\Gamma := (X_{t_1},\ldots,X_{t_n})$, we know that $\Gamma$ is Gaussian, hence $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Gaussian process.

The process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ does not have differentiable sample paths; actually not even continuous ones. *Indeed*: The independence implies $X_t-X_0 \sim N(0,2)$ for any $t \geq 0$. In particular,

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \mathbb{P}(|X_{t}-X_0|>\varepsilon) = \mathbb{P}(|G|> \varepsilon)>0$$

where $G \sim N(0,2)$. This shows that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is not stochastically continuous at $t=0$; hence not continuous. One can even show that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ does not have measurable sample paths.

**Remark** Please note that $\text{cov}(X_s,X_t)=0$ does in general **not** imply the independence of the random variables as long as you do not **assume** that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Gaussian process.

Answer (score 1):

> Is X a Gaussian process?

No. Please check any definition of "Gaussian process".

> Are the sample paths of X Differentiable?

They may be and they may not be differentiable. Please check some examples.

Speaking of which, which examples of Gaussian processes do you know?

Comment: Could you explain why it is not a Guassian process? All the finite dimensional distributions of X have a multivariate normal distribution. About the second part, do you mean that some sample paths are differentiable and some are not? I am not sure what you mean by "check some examples". Thanks.

Comment: "All the finite dimensional distributions of X have a multivariate normal distribution". How do you know they have? I see nothing in the hypothesis guaranteeing this.

Comment: Given any finite number of points, we know that they are i.i.d. and normally distributed so we are looking at a multivariate normal distribution with zero correlation. Am I missing something?

Comment: You just introduced the hypothesis that the random variables are **independent**. This is (crucial and) not mentioned in the question. Sure it holds?

Comment: Yes. The points are i.i.d. samples of a standard normal distribution.

Comment: @Vahid So why do you not mention this (crucial) assumption when asking the question? Perhaps you should considerate updating your question. And, by the way: It seems that you have an idea how to answer (at least) the first question. What's wrong about adding your own thoughts to your posting? It makes it much easier to give an appropriate answer.

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. I will update the question.

Comment: Did you downvote, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, because the answer is not "useful" (perhaps even misleading?) given the edited version of the question.

Comment: Oh I see: you mean that after $n$ comments to try to make you realize that the question is ill-posed, you finally feel that something is amiss, modify the question (which is still not correct, if ever you are interested), and then downvote an answer posted **before** all said comments because it does not correspond to the modified version of the question? I am impressed. Helping you any further would be absurd, surely you agree?

Comment: Yes that was my only intention: to indicate that is not suited to the modified version. Perhaps I am not fully familiar with the meaning of downvoting and I apologize for that. Once it is edited I will undo the downvote (it is locked now). Also I think I have shown that I am interested. If you think helping would be absurd, that's your decision. I appreciate your help so far.